# No access with SP Designer after change to FBA

Tags: sharepoint, sharepoint-designer, fba

two days ago I changed the authentication of my site from "Windows" into "Forms". So far so good, users are now in a SQL Express 2005 and it works fine. 
The problem is now, I have have no access to the Site with my SP Deigner 2007. Does he only support Windows-Authentication? Visual Studio ist the same, I get error message to enable Windows Authentication on IIS, but I can´t because "Forms" is enabled. 
Does anyone had the same problem? What can I do?

Thanx a lot, fiuman007

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes SharePoint designer doesn't work with Forms Authentication. What I normally do is extend the site on a second web app and enable that with Windows Auth. Any SPD work is then done through this alternate url/port.

Comment: Refer the Answer Below. SPD SP2 and MOSS SP2 will fix this Issue.

Comment: Oh I didn't know SP2 fixed this. Better!

Answer (score 2):

You need to Install the MOSS SP2 & SharePoint Designer SP2 to get the FBA working with the SharePoint designer. Refer [this](http://blogs.msdn.com/sharepoint/archive/2009/05/13/update-on-sharepoint-forms-based-authentication-fba-and-office-client.aspx) post , same fix applies for the SPD as well.

Answer (score 1):

ok, I found the way how to use SP Designer w/o authentication. If I go to IE, login as admin, click on "login automatically", the I can go to File and open it with Share Point Designer!
You also must put the site in secure sites in IE.